# function is not defined when I click on a button

Tags: javascript, scope

I generate modal forms using function  `function makeModalEnroll(name, description, i, id)`
And in one of my lines there is a string

```
modal += '<button type="button" id="enroll' + i + '" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="send(this.id);"> Enroll <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> </button>';
```

I've got function `send` and for now I submit form with `id = 0`

```
function send(id) {
    alert(id);
    var c = id.charAt(id.length - 1);
    alert(c);
    $('#enrollForm0').ajaxSubmit({url: 'enroll.html', type: 'post'});
};
```

But browser says that `ReferenceError: send is not defined`.
I tried to put function `send` before and after function `makeModalEnroll` but this error is always occurs.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: put the send function first on your script, because it's not using any other function inside, so you'll be sure that is is already defined

Comment: It did not solve the problem. @ReeCube I don't get it. Where to put it? These all functions are inside `$(function() {`

Comment: I put it before `$(function() {` and it seems to work now

Comment: yes, just put it before anything else ;)

Answer (score 1):

May be you don't expose your function to the global scope, try this:

```
window.send = function(id) {
    alert(id);
    var c = id.charAt(id.length - 1);
    alert(c);
    $('#enrollForm0').ajaxSubmit({url: 'enroll.html', type: 'post'});
};
```